# Convert RxJava Single to java CompletableFuture

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have a RxJava2 Single of Integer, how it can be converted to java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture?

```
Single<Integer> single = Single.just(1);
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture<Integer> cf = ???
```

Comment: Are you looking for `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(1)`?

Comment: @ernest_k, yes, not really, we need to wait for single completion first, and complete CompletableFuture then

Comment: @ernest_k, see my answer

Comment: Then please add that to your question. It isn't clear whether you what the completable future to be resolved when your `Single` completes, or you want the completablefuture version of your rxjava code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [RxJavaJdk8Interop](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaJdk8Interop):

```
CompletionStage<Integer> cs = Single.just(1)
.delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.to(SingleInterop.get());
```

Answer (score 1):

That is how it can be done:

```
Single<Integer> just = Single.just(1);
CompletableFuture<Integer> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
just.subscribe(cf::complete, cf::completeExceptionally);
```